# Image of the Riemann-sphere

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

Let $S$ be the Riemann-sphere (the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$) and $\psi: S \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be defined by $$\psi(x_1, x_2, x_3)=\frac{x_1 + ix_2}{1-x_3}.$$ Let $\pi$ be a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that the intersection with $S$ is not empty. Show that $\psi(\pi \cap S)$ is a line or a circumference in $\mathbb{C}$.

It's easy to see that if the plane has normal vector $(0,0,k)$, the image is a circumference. But i can't generalize the result.

Comment: Are you familiar with Möbius transformations?

Comment: Note, if have not already, your given function $\psi$ is the stereographic projection of the unit sphere onto the equatorial plane from the north pole. Note also a plane intersecting the unit sphere is a circle on the sphere. Can you see which circle on the sphere stereographically projects to circles and which to lines? (Hint: Consider circles on the sphere that don't go through the north pole and cirlcles that do go through the north pole.) This may give you some geometric view of what's going on here.

Comment: Also, minor technical point: the intersection should be more than a singleton.

Comment: @whacka Mobius transformations is in the next chapter of my book, so no.

Comment: @bonsoon Yes, i can imagine the geometric idea of your hint. The circles on the sphere that go through the north pole would be the lines. The other circles would be the circles on $\mathbb{C}$, is that correct? I was trying to find an analytic proof using the very definition of $\psi$ but, again, i couldn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We first note that $\psi$ has an inverse function, given by
$$
\psi^{-1}(x + iy) = \left(\frac{2x}{x^2 + y^2 + 1}, \frac{2y}{x^2 + y^2 + 1}, \frac{x^2 + y^2 - 1}{x^2 + y^2 + 1}\right).
$$
Let now $P$ be a plane in $\mathbb R^3$ given by
$$
P := \left\{ (x_1, x_2, x_3) \in \mathbb R^3 \middle| \sum_{j=1}^3 a_j x_j = b \right\}.
$$
First, we cover the case where the north pole (i. e. the vector $(0, 0, 1)$) is not contained within the plane. This implies that $a_3 \neq b$, since otherwise the north pole would be contained. Let $x \in P \cap S_2$. If $a := (a_1, a_2, a_3)$, we have due to the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$
a \cdot x \le \|a\| \|x\| = \|a\|
$$
and therefore, since $x \in P$,
$$
\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^3 a_j^2} \ge b \Rightarrow \sum_{j=1}^3 a_j^2 \ge b^2 \\
\Rightarrow a_1^2 + a_2^2 \ge b^2 - a_3^2 \ge (b - a_3)(b + a_3) \\
\Rightarrow \frac{a_1^2 + a_2^2}{(a_3 - b)^2} + \frac{b + a_3}{a_3 - b} \ge 0.
$$

Now if $x + iy$ is contained in $\psi(P)$, then we have
$$
a_1 \frac{2x}{x^2 + y^2 + 1} + a_2 \frac{2y}{x^2 + y^2 + 1} + a_3 \frac{x^2 + y^2 - 1}{x^2 + y^2 + 1} = b.
$$

We want this to be a circle equation, i. e. an equation of the form
$$
(x - \lambda)^2 + (y - \mu)^2 = r
$$
for some $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb R$ and $r \in \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$. Hence, we group all the terms of $x$ and $y$ together and complete the squares:
$$
a_1 \frac{2x}{x^2 + y^2 + 1} + a_2 \frac{2y}{x^2 + y^2 + 1} + a_3 \frac{x^2 + y^2 - 1}{x^2 + y^2 + 1} = b \\
\Leftrightarrow 2 a_1 x + 2 a_2 y + a_3 x^2 + a_3 y^2 - a_3 = b (x^2 + y^2 + 1) \\
\Leftrightarrow (a_3 - b) x^2 + 2 a_1 x + (a_3 - b) y^2 + 2 a_2 y = b + a_3 \\
\Leftrightarrow x^2 + 2 x \frac{a_1}{a_3 - b} + y^2 + 2 y \frac{a_2}{a_3 - b} = \frac{b + a_3}{a_3 - b} \\
\Leftrightarrow
\left( x - \frac{a_1}{a_3 - b} \right)^2 + \left( y - \frac{a_2}{a_3 - b} \right)^2 = \frac{b + a_3}{a_3 - b} + \frac{a_1^2 + a_2^2}{(a_3 - b)^2}
$$

Now we consider the case $b = a_3$. Then we have
$$
a_1 \frac{2x}{x^2 + y^2 + 1} + a_2 \frac{2y}{x^2 + y^2 + 1} + a_3 \frac{x^2 + y^2 - 1}{x^2 + y^2 + 1} = b \\
\Leftrightarrow 2 a_1 x + 2 a_2 y + a_3 x^2 + a_3 y^2 - a_3 = b (x^2 + y^2 + 1) \\
\Leftrightarrow 2 a_1 x + 2 a_2 y = b + a_3,
$$
which defines a line.