# A metric in $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$

Tags: complex-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $$d(z,z')=\frac{2|z-z'|}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2} \sqrt{1+|z'|^2}}, \mbox{if z,z' $\in \mathbb{C}$}$$ and $$d(z,z')=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2}}, \mbox{if z $\in \mathbb{C}$ and $z'=\infty$}$$

where $|z-z'|$ is the euclidean metric. Show that $d$ is a metric in $\mathbb{C}^{\infty}$.

I've already proved the easiest properties, it just remain the triangle inequality.

$$d(z,z')=\frac{2|z-z'|}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2} \sqrt{1+|z'|^2}}\leq\frac{2|z-z''|}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2} \sqrt{1+|z'|^2}} + \frac{2|z''-z'|}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2} \sqrt{1+|z'|^2}}$$ but i'm stuck here, i must get 
$$d(z,z')\leq\frac{2|z-z''|}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2} \sqrt{1+|z''|^2}} + \frac{2|z''-z'|}{\sqrt{1+|z''|^2} \sqrt{1+|z'|^2}}=d(z,z'') + d(z'',z')$$

Answer (score 1):

In another question you asked today ([Image of the Riemann-sphere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1439467/image-of-the-riemann-sphere)), you talked about the stereographic projection from $\mathbb C$ to the unit sphere, a map that can be extended to $\infty$ by sending $\infty$ to the north pole.

Let's call that map $S: \mathbb C^{*} \to S^2$, where the letter $S$ is for "stereographic projection", and $\mathbb C^{*}$ means the "extended complex plane", or whatever your text calls it when you consider complex numbers and an extra "point at infinity".

Let's use the $\| \cdot \|$ to denote the usual metric on 3-space, so that the distance from $P$ to $Q$ is $\| Q - P \|$.

Then I'll bet your function $d$ can be written, up to a constant multiple, as something like this:
$$
d(z_1, z_2) = \| S(z_1) - S(z_2) \|.
$$

(You need to show this, of course, but that's some messy algebra and nothing more).

**Side note:** How'd I know this? Because that's how someone got the idea to use $d$ as the definition of distance in the first place, and if your prof. didn't tell you that, you should have serious doubts: it's just irresponsible to pretend that things like this arise out of whole cloth, or spring full-grown from the head of Zeus.

Anyhow, let's assume that you *do* manage to establish the equivalence I wrote. Then the triangle inequality for $d$ is a consequence of the triangle inequality for $\| \cdot \|$, which is proved in many linear algebra books as a consequence of the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.